# To figure out whether $r = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is an algebraic integer or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I have tried to find a monic polynomial for $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ without success; I can see it is an algebraic number since $2r^2-2r-1=0$, where $r=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Is there a method to find monic polynomials, or show that it is not an algebraic integer? I am quite lost.

Comment: You are already done. The minimal polynomial is not monic, so it is not an algebraic integer, like $1/2$.

Comment: How do I prove that it is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: It's irreducible over the rationals.

Comment: Oh makes sense, thank you!

Comment: What's $r^2-r$?

Comment: quadratic algebraic integers are $\mathbb Z+\sqrt D\mathbb Z$ for $D\equiv\color{red}3\pmod4$ and $\mathbb Z+\frac{1+\sqrt D}2\mathbb Z $ for $D\equiv1$ or $2\pmod4$, $D$ square-free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposition from Neukirch ANT page $8$:

> Let $A$ be integrally closed in its field of fractions. An element $\beta\in L$ is integral over $A$ if and only if its minimal polynomial $\min_{\beta,A}(x)\in A[x]$.

In this case, $L=\mathbb{Q}$, and $A=\mathbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{Z}$ being a UFD means that it is integrally closed, with minimal polynomial $x^2-x-1/2$ you found. This polynomial is not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so that it is not an algebraic integer by the proposition.

The proof of the proposition goes as follows:

Let $\beta$ be integral over $A$, with monic polynomial $g(x)$. Then by definition, $\min_{\beta,A}(x)$ divides $g(x)$ in $K[x]$. Therefore every zero of $\min_{\beta,A}(x)$ is a zero of $g(x)$, and hence every zero $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$ is integral over $A$. Since $\min_{\beta,A}(x)=(x-\beta_1)\cdots(x-\beta_n)$, the coefficients are also integral over $A$ (being sums and products of integral elements). Since $A$ is integrally closed, $\min_{\beta,A}(x)\in A[x]$.

The converse follows trivially.

Other facts used were:

> UFDs are integrally closed (Page 8).
>
> $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD (FTA).